# Visualizing a parse tree with d3.js

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, parse-tree

I've been trying to obtain a visual representation of a parse tree by generating an HTML file that uses `d3.js` to draw a tree. The file looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head><title> Tree Visualization </title></head>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function drawTree(o) {
        d3.select("#"+o.divID).select("svg").remove() 

        var viz = d3.select("#"+o.divID)
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", o.width)
            .attr("height", o.height)  

        var vis = viz.append("g")
            .attr("id","treeg")
            .attr("transform", "translate("+ o.padding +","+ o.padding +")") 

        var tree = d3.layout.tree()
            .size([o.width - (2 * o.padding), o.height - (2 * o.padding)]);

        var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
            .projection(function(d) { return [d.x, d.y]; });

        var nodes = tree.nodes(o.treeData);

        var link = vis.selectAll("pathlink")
            .data(tree.links(nodes)).enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("class", "link")
            .attr("d", diagonal)

        var node = vis.selectAll("g.node")
            .data(nodes).enter()
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })

        node.append("circle")
            .attr("r", 10)
            .style("fill", function(d) { return (d.children) ? "#E14B3B" : "#1C8B98" });

        node.append("svg:text")
            .attr("dx", function(d) { return d.children ? 0 : 0; })
            .attr("dy", function(d) { return d.children ? 5 : 5; })
            .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children ? "middle" : "middle"; })
            .style("fill", "white").text(function(d) { return d.name; })
    }
 </script>

<body onLoad="drawTree({divID: 'viz', width: 600, height: 400, padding: 50, treeData: {name: 'S', children: [{name: 'S', children: [{name: 'S', children: [{name: 'S', children: [{name: 'x'}]}, {name: 'S', children: [{name: 'y'}]}, {name: '*'}]}, {name: 'S', children: [{name: '1'}]}, {name: '+'}]}, {name: 'S', children: [{name: 'S', children: [{name: '1'}]}, {name: '-'}]}, {name: '+'}]}})">
<div id="viz"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

What I want it to look like:
[image: this]

What it currently looks like:
[image: this]

I'm completely new to `d3.js` and, to be honest, the code is taken from an example and only modified by me. I managed to get to this point this way, but I just can't figure out where it goes wrong.

I'd appreciate every bit of help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your CSS , set the path fill to none. Like this: `path { fill: none; }`.

Comment: If I do that, the links are completely invisible.

Comment: Set the stroke (any color) and the stroke width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to update the styles . Add below lines

```
.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

For node circle border

```
circle {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}
```

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/scsiva1991/22vx8v18/1/)

Comment: Ah, thank you very much! Do you know how I can draw an outline around the nodes as well?

Comment: Do you mean border around the node circles?

Comment: Yes, like in the first image.